# Unable to access Geoserver on Ubuntu Server

Tags: geoserver, ubuntu

I installed the complete opengeo-suite on Ubuntu Server and it displays that it is working fine here,

```
opengeo-geoserver:
  Installed: 2.5
  Candidate: 2.5
  Version table:
 *** 2.5 0
        500 http://apt.opengeo.org/ubuntu/ lucid/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

But when I try to run the url (http://serverurl/geoserver/web) i am not able to get the admin page.

Comment: use h-ttp://localhost:8080/geoserver/web

Comment: it is on ubuntu server, i can access it only using terminal, right? so localhost won't work

Comment: http://ubuntuserver.info/2007/04/25/install-a-web-browser-lynx/

Comment: Actually if I run `xdg-open <url>` that does it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that on installing Geoserver, it is installed on port 8080. By default the apache2 server on Ubuntu Server 11.04 also runs on the same port. So this conflicts the situation and we cannot run the two different servers on the same port. Therefore,

```
service apache2 stop
service tomcat6 stop
```

tomcat6 is the server on which the Geoserver runs. After you have stopped both, you can start the tomcat6 again,

```
service tomcat6 start
```

Now you will need to reconfigure the port of apache2 by going to the [DocumentRoot](http://tareq.wedevs.com/2012/04/changing-apache-document-root-in-ubuntu/) and changing the port to 80.

Once you have done that, restart the apache again.

```
service apache2 start
```

And you are good to go.